# Binding to ComboBox with converter in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I have a numeric value that I wish to be converted to a more user-friendly string format when it's displayed. I already have an IValueConverter called `FlightLevelConverter` that I'm using to do this for a normal `TextBlock` UI item where it works fine.

I now wish to apply the converter to a `ComboBox` of altitude choices, but I can't get it to work.

This is the relevant part of the `XAML` I'm using for the `ComboBox`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <status:FlightLevelConverter x:Key="FlightLevelConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<ComboBox x:Name="AltitudeCombo" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Width="100">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FlightLevelConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

It displays the un-converted numeric values, not the nice string values. I get no errors and if I set a breakpoint in the converter it doesn't get hit, showing that the converter is never called.

I've spent all morning trawling the Internet in general and *StackOverflow* in particular to try to discover what I'm doing wrong, but haven't found out anything useful.

Why is my converter not being called? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please post your whole xaml file along with how you populating the items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you add the items to the ComboBox?

You should set the [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property to a collection of numeric values, e.g.

```
List<double> values = new List<double>();
values.Add(2.1);
values.Add(3.2);
values.Add(4.3);
values.Add(5.4);
AltitudeCombo.ItemsSource = values;
```

If you add ComboBoxItems like this

```
AltitudeCombo.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = 1.4 });
```

the ItemTemplate and hence the binding with its converter won't be applied.

Comment: Aha.  This seems like the problem then.  I am adding items as per your second example. I will try setting the ItemsSource.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note also that the binding has a [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc491086(v=vs.95).aspx) property, which might eliminate the need for a (simple) converter.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short working sample. You can compare code...

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:bys="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <bys:MyList x:Key="lst"/>
            <bys:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource lst}" SelectedIndex="0">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox >
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
public class MyList : List<int> {
    public MyList() {
        AddRange(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
    }
}

public class MyConverter : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        return String.Format("<<{0}>>", value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ComboBox.ItemTemplate is not applicable to the main part of the ComboBox if ComboBox.IsEditable == true. It works for dropdown list entries only. Try to set ComboBox.IsEditable == false. It might help.

Comment: ComboBox is not editable by default. No need to set `IsEditable`.

Comment: The Silverlight ComboBox doesn't support editing, and IsEditable is always false.